# unexpected keyword argument 'max_length' in AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS

Tags: python, django

I'm making a Django site and I'm trying to put the `MaxLengthValidator` in `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` in the settings file, but I keep getting this error:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'`

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 8,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.core.validators.MaxLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'max_length': 32,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Comment: that's all python code related to that authentication ?

Comment: @Andriy yeah that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `MaxLengthValidator` class you need to use `limit_value` key.

Ref: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L304